# How can I cut metal roofing and siding into pieces during demolition?

Tags: cutting, metal-cutting

I'm tearing down an old single wide. What is an easy way of cutting the siding (aluminum) and roof (corrugated steel) into manageable pieces.

Answer (score 2):

Circular saw (e.g. Skilsaw) with a carbide-toothed framing or demolition blade (or two, or five). Good eye, ear, and skin protection. Reciprocating saw (e.g. Sawzall) for the tight spots.

Comment: I hope you meant to say use the circular saw on the material AFTER it's been removed from the trailer.  Using a circ saw on vertical surfaces seems quite dangerous to me...

Comment: I imagine it seems that way to the layperson. It's a routine operation for a carpenter. Upside-down, too (such as when retrofitting vented aluminum soffit over  plywood).

Comment: I agree with carbide tipped saw I use finish blades more teeth so the chips are smaller. Harbor freight has a tin cutter or nibbler that is not very expensive to get into tight spots but the skill saw is my go to for straight cuts and much faster.+

Comment: Fair enough - probably not something to recommend to the inexperienced :)